# View Contact information from contacts lookup

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have created custom entity called "Property"  that contains a **Lookup** field "Owner1" (“Contact" Entity). I need to display some of the contact info like (Email,Mobile,etc) when the user selects "Owner1" as read only.

My question is: Is it possible to accomplish that through javascript only?

I tried something like

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_owner1").getValue()[0].id
```

but I found that not all contact attributes are available on the client side
ex:
`Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_owner1").getValue()[0].emailaddress1 //(undefined)`

what is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Quick view form](https://dynamicscrmherald.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/understanding-and-using-quick-view-form-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013/) to achieve this without code.

You asked through JS only, then you have to retrieve other attributes of contact on change of lookup field using [Service call.](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmandunifiedservicedesk/archive/2017/04/13/javascript-odata-query) (But you said read-only?)

This is a sample odata query you can use with OrganizationData.svc:

```
var selectQuery = "/ContactSet?&$filter=ContactId eq guid'" + lookupid + "'&$select= emailaddress1,MobilePhone";
```

Btw, you have long way to go. Read the documentation a lot & follow blogs. Read SDK thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you so much Arun, I didn't know that there was such thing as Quick view form that's why I asked about java script.
That was pretty easy!! I appreciate your advice